# In the gearman client side, How do I remove a job which attempted to call a nonexisted function?

Tags: php, gearman

I'm using the Gearman php API.

In my client side, gclient.php:

```
    $gClient = new GearmanClient();
    $gClient->addServer('127.0.0.1', 4730);
    $gClient->setTimeout(2000);
    $ret = $gClient->doNormal('functionNameNonexist', json_encode(array(
        'k' => 'v',
    )));
    $returnCode = $gClient->returnCode();
    if ($returnCode != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
    {
      echo "bad return code: {$returnCode}\n";
    }
```

By running the command `gearadmin --show-jobs`, I can see the jobs queue became longer after each time the php script is executed.

Is there a way to remove/cancel those jobs that have been stayed in the queue over like 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is two fast ways to remove jobs in the queue:

1. Use the gearman CLI tool in worker mode to grab the jobs and send them to /dev/null:

> gearman -n -w -f your_function_name > /dev/null

2. Restart gearmand. Note that if you are using a persistent job store, you will need to delete the job records from the table.  If you're not using a persistent job store, be careful - you will lose all other jobs as well.

Comment: Is there PHP GearmanClient remove/cancel function to remove all tasks from the queue? Looked at docs, seems that there isn't